# R shiny: How to change the width of a progress-bar

Tags: css, r, shiny

How to edit the CSS to change the width of the progress-bar?

[image]

I put in

```
  div.progress-bar{
    width:100px
  }

  progress-bar{
    width:100px
  }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bar has an `Id = file1_progress` so you can style that. Have a look at my example below, I set mine to `100px`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My R Shiny App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file',  'Choose file to upload.' ),width=3),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#file_progress { max-width: 100px; }")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]